# change all values in the dataframe for all the columns except for a particular column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to change all values in the dataframe for all the columns except for a particular column. How do i do that?

***Problem 1:*** My below code will change all the values in dataframe where ever it finds 13. But I do not want to change in column C.

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c(12,14,13), B=c(16,13,18)),c=c(13,20,21))
df[df == 13]<-NA
print(df)
```

I also tried doing something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c(12,14,13), B=c(16,13,18)),c=c(13,20,21))
df[df[,1:ncol(df)-1] == 13]<-NA
print(df)
```

But they are not working properly.

***Problem 2:***
Also, I want to change values to NA in all the rows if it find's 13 in column C.
So, dataframe will look like :

```
A .   B .  C
NA   NA   13
14   13   20
13   18   21
```

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all 13s with NA in each of the columns except for C with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-one_of("c")), recode, `13`=NA_real_)
```

You can set all values for rows with C==13 to NA with

```
df[df$c==13,setdiff(names(df), "c")]<-NA
```

or using parts of `dplyr`

```
notc <- setdiff(names(df), "c")
df[df$c==13,notc]<-df[df$c==13,notc] %>% mutate_all(function(x) NA)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define which subset of your data.frame you want to apply the condition as well as defining that subset within that condition.

Also, `1:ncol(df)-1` subtracts 1 from all the sequence so you would get (in this case) `0` and `1` instead of `1` and `2`.

```
df[,1:(ncol(df)-1)][df[,1:(ncol(df)-1)]==13]  <-NA

#    A  B  c 
# 1 12 16 13 
# 2 14 NA 20 
# 3 NA 18 21
```

For the second part of your question same approach can be used; You apply the condition only on column `c` (you can use `df[,ncol(df)]` instead of `df$c` if that's desired) and replace values only in the first two columns:

```
df[,1:(ncol(df)-1)][(df$c == 13),] <- NA

#    A  B  c 
# 1 NA NA 13 
# 2 14 13 20 
# 3 13 18 21
```

Answer (score 3):

```
indices = which(df == "13", arr.ind = TRUE)
replace(df, indices[names(df)[indices[,2]]!= "c",], NA)
#   A  B  c
#1 12 16 13
#2 14 NA 20
#3 NA 18 21

replace(df, cbind(which(df$c == "13"), (1:NCOL(df))[-which(names(df) == "c")]), NA)
#   A  B  c
#1 NA NA 13
#2 14 13 20
#3 13 18 21
```

Comment: Can you explain [indices[,2]]!= "c",] ?